# getting stacktrace from core dump

Tags: linux, coredump

How can I get a stack trace from a core dump file? The file is about 14 mb and is generated after my application exits saying "segmentation fault"

I'm on Red Hat 5.5

Comment: By the way is your application written in C++?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
gdb /usr/bin/myapp.binary corefile
```

Then, use one of:

```
(gdb) bt
(gdb) bt full
(gdb) info threads
(gdb) thread apply all bt
(gdb) thread apply all bt full
```

Note that installing debug symbols for the related libraries will help

Comment: How do I find my corefile? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If you're on a systemd-based system then you can run `coredumpctl gdb -1` to run gdb on the last coredump.